# Calculate the basis of the sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have the bases of two subspaces, Y1 and Y2, and I want to calculate the basis of Y1+Y2.

I put the vectors of the two bases in a matrix and performed row operations until the matrix is in row reduced form. Since the matrix is in this form, the vectors represented by the non-zero lines of the resulting matrix are linearly independent and therefore they are a basis of Y1+Y2.

Is my method correct? If not which is?

Comment: What you've done sounds correct - but I can't be sure because you are not using standard terminology. You could edit your question to post an example showing your work. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is correct. 'Line operations' are *row operations* and 'climax form' is *row reduced form*.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, you have to consider the set of all basis vectors of two subspaces put them as rows into a matrix and then select a basis by the RREF (Row Reduced Echelon Form).

Comment: so if $V$ has a basis $(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$ and $W$ has a basis $(u_1,\cdots,u_m)$ then we have to consider the matrix of $n+m$ rows formed by $v_1\cdots,v_n,u_1,\cdots,u_m$ ?

Comment: @PermQi Yes exactly and then calculate the RREF.